Is Mutual Recursion Supported in Kotlin?
I stumbled upon an old question from 8 years ago (Kotlin: Tail recursion for mutually recursive functions), which discusses tail recursion in Kotlin. However, my concern is with mutual recursion for functions.
When attempting to use code similar to the provided example, I encountered an error stating that 'foo' is not declared. Has Kotlin introduced any updates or features that support mutual recursion? Is there a decorator or alternative approach that enables mutual recursion in Kotlin?
fun match(xs: Deque): Boolean {
    fun boo(xs: Deque): Boolean {
        ...
        return ... foo(...)
    }

    fun foo(xs: Deque): Boolean {
        ...
        return ... boo(...)
    }

    return boo(xs)
}
...

Error: Unresolved reference: function name

Can you move them out of the match function?

If somehow I manage to move them out, I'm certainly positive that later I'll have some similar code in a class or some sort of nested thing and I'll get around the same issue.

there is no way to make nested functions call each other?

Nested functions can indeed call each other. See my answer.

@k314159 I see, it has a really weird syntax. Weird that in 2024 cannot do this.

@k314159 maybe there is something like how access control is used in swift with public and private?

No, it's nothing to do with access control at all. It's everything to do with the fact that a nested function is declared exactly like a variable. You can't access a variable inside a function until you declare it, so you can't access a local nested function until you declare it either.

Leviathan's answer explains why you get this error.
If you really want to define both functions locally, you can do so by forward-declaring foo as a variable of the required function type, and then assigning it to a function body that calls boo after boo is declared. Like this:
fun match(xs: Deque): Boolean {

    lateinit var foo: (Deque) -> Boolean

    fun boo(xs: Deque): Boolean {
        ...
        return ... foo(...)
    }

    foo = fun(xs: Deque): Boolean {
        ...
        return ... boo(...)
    }

    return boo(xs)
}



Your problem has nothing to do with the linked post or even recursion.
foo and boo are nested functions, so they are only declared when the surrounding match function is executed. For this the order in which they appear is relevant: boo cannot access foo because foo doesn't exist yet. foo, however, can access boo.
To solve this make both functions members of a class or an interface, or you can just declare them as top-level functions on the file level. Then they can see and call each other.

I'm currently studying Racket and have reached the topic of local bindings. In Racket, constructs such as let, let*, and letrec allow for referencing earlier bindings, later bindings, and support mutual recursion.
In the case of Kotlin, mutual recursion as shown in the previous example cannot be achieved due to the lack of a mechanism for referencing functions in the same logical scope? (I'm not suggesting that Kotlin's limitations are exactly like those in Racket, but is a similar concept applied here?)

When functions are in the same class (same logical scope), they can reference themselves. The same applies to top-level functions. A function inside a function is a different case, because that scope will only exist at runtime, not at compile time. I don't know how Racket works, but for Kotlin that's the relevant difference why it works in one case and not in the other.
